# whats wrong with pygame part of this code?

Tags: python, pygame

pygame window freezes everytime I run this program. 
I am using windows. 
Everything else works fine except when pygame window pops up. Please help!
I have seen some of the posts here suggest to use `pygame.event.get()` but it doesn't work for me!

```
class DriveDataHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
class VideoStreamHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):   
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port1,port3):
        self.host = host
        self.port1 = port1
        #self.port2 = port2
        self.port3 = port3

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
    def video_stream(self, host, port):
        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), VideoStreamHandler)
        s.serve_forever()
    def sensor_stream(self, host, port):
        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), SensorDataHandler)
        s.serve_forever()
    def drive_stream(self, host, port):

        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), DriveDataHandler)
        s.serve_forever()
    def start(self):

f __name__ == '__main__':
    h, p1, p3 = "127.0.1.1", 8000, 8004

    ts = Server(h, p1, p3)
    ts.start()
```

Comment: That's too much code to review. Please create a copy of the code, then remove everything that is not related to the problem (e.g. all print statements in your case, also all commented code). That'll be an [mcve]. The chance of getting an answer with lesser code will increase. Also, please point out at which line the code stops. I haven't found a PyGame window in your code, which is why I can't answer it.

Comment: Totally agree with Thomas. In addition to that, I would suggest you remove all "try" instructions, because I think they might be "hiding" the real problem (e.g. I saw a try, which wraps a huge part of code inside VideoStreamHandler, with no except clause, only finally!)

Comment: when I run code it open window and end work - it need some loop to keep it open. In normal game is `while True` with `pygame.event.get()` but you run it in separted thread so it can't keep running main thread.

Comment: usually GUIs has to run in main thread. In thread it may not get events from system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port1,port3):
        self.host = host
        self.port1 = port1
        #self.port2 = port2
        self.port3 = port3


    def video_stream(self, host, port):

        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), VideoStreamHandler)
        s.serve_forever()

    def sensor_stream(self, host, port):

        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), SensorDataHandler)
        s.serve_forever()

    def drive_stream(self, host, port):

        s = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), DriveDataHandler)
        s.serve_forever()

    def start(self):
        drive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.drive_stream, args=(self.host, self.port3))
##        sensor_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.sensor_stream, args=(self.host, self.port2))
##        sensor_thread.daemon = True #this thread will be killed after the main program exits
##        sensor_thread.start()
        drive_thread.daemon = True
        drive_thread.start()

        video_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.video_stream, args=(self.host, self.port1))
        video_thread.daemon = True #this thread will be killed after the main program exits
        video_thread.start()

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
        finish = False
        while not finish:
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for e in events:
                if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    finish = True
        pygame.quit()

        #self.video_stream(self.host, self.port1)
```

However, once you do quit, what happens to all the threads you've spawned? You need to shutdown the server properly.